# Communicating between two controllers in angularjs 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to communicate two `controllers`.

```
var main = angular.module('starter', ["ionic", "ngCordova", "starter.services"]);
```

`cart-ctrl.js`

```
main.controller('CartCtrl',
  ["$scope", "global",
  function($scope, global) {
  $scope.$on("globalvar", function() {
    //alert("from service cart: " + global.cart.items);
    console.log("from service cart: " + global.cart.items);
    $scope.carts = global.cart.items;
  });
}]);
```

`menu-ctrl.js`

```
main.controller('AppCtrl',
  ["$scope", "$state", "global",
  function($scope, $state, global) {
  $scope.cart_click = function() {
    global.updateCart();
    $state.go('app.cart');
  }
}]);
```

`services.js`

```
var service = angular.module("starter.services", []);
service.factory("global", ["$rootScope", "database", 
  function($rootScope, database) {
  var service = {
    cart: {
        items: [],
        count: 0
    },
    broadcastItem: function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("globalvar");
    },
    updateCart: function() {
      database.select_cart(function(p_cart) {
        this.cart.items = p_cart;
        alert("service cart: " + JSON.stringify(this.cart.items));
      });
      this.broadcastItem();
    }
  };
  return service;
}]);
```

What I wanted to happen is when I click a the tab (which triggeres the `cart_click()`), the cart list will re-update. However no value is passed into `CartCtrl`. I wonder what's wrong in this code. `service.cart.items` has a value when I passed the value from the `database`.

Comment: Create a fiddle. Replace the database code with a direct function to simulate your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have 2 options.

- You can $scope.cart_click => $rootScope.cart_click.
- You can $emit, $broadcast and $on

And see more in https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `this.broadcastItem();` inside the callback of your database call. Also context of `this` inside the callback is not actually of the same service. Update your code as

```
updateCart: function() {
  var self = this;
  database.select_cart(function(p_cart) {
    self.cart.items = p_cart;
    self.broadcastItem();
    alert("service cart: " + JSON.stringify(self.cart.items));
  });
}
```